# How to execute write method in function that changes value in slidebar?

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy

When the slide bar value changes, it tries to write a packet.
I am using the example,
I made a function and tried it, but a null error occurs. (discoverService, characteristic.., etc.)
How can I solve this?

I'm using flutter_blue

In the flutter_blue example, write works fine.

I'm flutter beginer.
I need your help. thank you.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue

*onWriteData*

```
  var data = [0x80, 0x80, 0xF0, 0x7D, 0x05, 0x00, 0x0E, 0x01, 60, 100, 00,0x80, 0xF7];

FlutterBlue flutterBlue = FlutterBlue.instance;

BluetoothDevice device;

BluetoothService service;



onWriteData() async {
List<BluetoothService> services = await device.discoverServices();
services.forEach((service) {
});

var characteristics = service.characteristics;

for(BluetoothCharacteristic c in characteristics) {

  List<int> value = await c.read();

  print(value);
  await c.write(data);

}
}
```

*slideBar class*

```
    class slidecontrollerr extends State<slidecontroller> {
 static double volumeValue = 60;


  void onVolumeChanged(double value) async { **// I want to execute the write function here**

    setState(()  {
      volumeValue = value;
    });
        onWriteData();  **//error**
  }

  @override 

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
.

.

.
```

[Error Code][1]

```
E/flutter ( 5640): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'discoverServices' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 5640): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 5640): Tried calling: discoverServices()
E/flutter ( 5640): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
E/flutter ( 5640): #1      onWriteData (package:auto_humidity/main.dart:467:48)
E/flutter ( 5640): #2      slidecontrollerr.onVolumeChanged (package:auto_humidity/main.dart:1489:5)
E/flutter ( 5640): #3      RenderRadialAxisParent.createPointerValueChangedArgs (package:syncfusion_flutter_gauges/src/radial_gauge/axis/radial_axis_parent_widget.dart:584:43)
E/flutter ( 5640): #4      RenderRadialAxisParent._setCurrentPointerValue (package:syncfusion_flutter_gauges/src/radial_gauge/axis/radial_axis_parent_widget.dart:548:5)
E/flutter ( 5640): #5      RenderRadialAxisParent._updateDragValue (package:syncfusion_flutter_gauges/src/radial_gauge/axis/radial_axis_parent_widget.dart:527:7)
E/flutter ( 5640): #6      RenderRadialAxisParent._updatePointerValue (package:syncfusion_flutter_gauges/src/radial_gauge/axis/radial_axis_parent_widget.dart:452:7)
E/flutter ( 5640): #7      RenderRadialAxisParent._handleDragUpdate (package:syncfusion_flutter_gauges/src/radial_gauge/axis/radial_axis_parent_widget.dart:339:5)
E/flutter ( 5640): #8      DragGestureRecognizer._checkUpdate.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/monodrag.dart:436:55)
E/flutter ( 5640): #9      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter ( 5640): #10     DragGestureRecognizer._checkUpdate (package:flutter/src/gestures/monodrag.dart:436:7)
E/flutter ( 5640): #11     DragGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/monodrag.dart:289:9)
E/flutter ( 5640): #12     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:93:12)
E/flutter ( 5640): #13     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:138:9)
E/flutter ( 5640): #14     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:397:8)
E/flutter ( 5640): #15     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:136:18)
E/flutter ( 5640): #16     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:122:7)
E/flutter ( 5640): #17     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:439:19)
E/flutter ( 5640): #18     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:419:22)
E/flutter ( 5640): #19     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:287:11)
E/flutter ( 5640): #20     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:374:7)
E/flutter ( 5640): #21     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:5)
E/flutter ( 5640): #22     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:296:7)
E/flutter ( 5640): #23     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:279:7)
E/flutter ( 5640): #24     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1370:13)
E/flutter ( 5640): #25     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
E/flutter ( 5640): #26     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7)
E/flutter ( 5640): #27     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:182:10)
E/flutter ( 5640): #28     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:282:7)
E/flutter ( 5640): #29     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:96:31)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to a specific `service` and `characteristics` of your BLE device

Here is a piece of code that I am using

```
final String serviceUUID = "0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
final String characteristicWriteUUID = "0000fff1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
final String characteristicReadUUID = "0000fff2-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
```

These services and characteristics must be set in the module itself by default or by you manually

```
  discoverServices(BluetoothDevice device) async {
    if (device == null) return;

    List<BluetoothService> services = await device.discoverServices();
    services.forEach((service) {
      // do something with service
      if (service.uuid.toString().toLowerCase() == serviceUUID) {
        service.characteristics.forEach((characteristic) {
          if (characteristic.uuid.toString().toLowerCase() == characteristicReadUUID) {
            targetReadCharacteristic = characteristic;
            _readData(targetReadCharacteristic);
          }
          if (characteristic.uuid.toString().toLowerCase() == characteristicWriteUUID) {
            targetWriteCharacteristic = characteristic;
            writeData(targetWriteCharacteristic, [0x49, 0x44, 0x02]);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }


  Future<void> writeData(characteristic, data) async{
    if (characteristic == null) return;
    try {
      List<int> bytes = data;
      await characteristic.write(bytes, withoutResponse: true );
      print("data: Send: $data");
    } catch (e) {
      print('Data Error ${e.message} | $data');
    }
  }

  _readData(characteristic) async {
    if (!characteristic.isNotifying) {
      await characteristic.setNotifyValue(true);
    }
    readSubScription = characteristic.value.listen((value) {
      List<int> readData = new List.from(value);

      if(readData.isNotEmpty && readData != []){
        print('BLE read data: $readData');
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: WOW, Thank you so much. You saved me.
but i got a problem. how can i solve Exceptions error?

I/flutter (14659): Data Error (d: [128, 128, 240, 125, 5, 0, 14, 1, 60, 100, 0, 128, 247])
I/chatty  (14659): uid=10249(com.example.humidityauto2) 1.ui identical 7 lines

Comment: @BigHead, replace it
`print('Data Error (' + "d: $data" + ')');`
with this
`print('Data Error ${e.message} | $data');`

Comment: You need to set the UUID as on your BLE modem.
You also need to connect to a BLE device
the characteristics of the modem must have appropriate settings for read / write / notifications

Comment: they can be checked using third-party software
(ex: lightblue)

Comment: Ok, I'll try and come back

Comment: My BLE module is set to enable read and write. I've tried a couple of ways, but the write doesn't work. And still I/chatty log is showing.